# Sorting an array of dictionaries based on dictionary values which are of Date type, without knowing the keys, in Swift 5.1?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, date, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries. Dictionaries are of [Int:Date] type. I want to sort this array based on the values of dictionary, recent dates first. Keys are of Int type, but they will be changed in runtime.

Here is the sample code. I use here random Ints as keys to demonstrate runtime:

```
var dates : [[Int:Date]] = []

let date1 = Date(timeInterval: 3000, since: Date())
let date2 = Date(timeInterval: 5000, since: Date())
let date3 = Date(timeInterval: 5000, since: Date())

let key1 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)
let key2 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)
let key3 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)

dates.append([key1:date1])
dates.append([key2:date2])
dates.append([key3:date3])
```

I try to use `sort` method of array but I have no idea about how to access the key (of `Int` type) and value (of `Date` type) of the dictionaries in the closure of `sort` method, with keys which will be changed in runtime...

```
dates.sort { (p1:[Int : Date], p2:[Int : Date]) -> Bool in
   // how to access keys of p1 and p2? I need them to compare values
}
```

If using this kind of array of dictionaries is not a good practice for sorting, what would you suggest? What is the best practice?

Update: Just taking the values from the dictionary and sorting them is not enough for me. I use keys to store values too and I need both keys and values after the sort. This is why I am using an array of dictionaries.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use a `[(key: Int, date: Date)]` instead, if the dictionary only has one KVP? Or better, create a custom struct and use an array of that custom struct.

Comment: Yes, it seems using a custom struct a better way. Or tuples, as Michael suggested. It seems storing values in dictionary keys is not a good idea.

Comment: Actually @Sweeper suggested using an array of tuples as well ;)

Comment: Ah yes, that is an array of tuples too. It was a long day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: `dict.values` has all the values that `dict`.

But why do you have an Array of dicts? Why don't you have one dict with more than one entry? And if you need that array of dicts: how do you want to compare the dates? From each dictionary get all values, and the newest Date of them and then compare only the newest dates in each dict?

Suggestion: If every dict only has one entry: use tuples instead:

```
typealias myDatatype = (someRandomInt: Int, aDateIChose: Date)
var dates : [myDatatype] = []

let date1 = Date(timeInterval: 3000, since: Date())
let date2 = Date(timeInterval: 5000, since: Date())
let date3 = Date(timeInterval: 5000, since: Date())

let key1 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)
let key2 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)
let key3 = Int.random(in: 1..<1000)

dates.append(contentsOf: [(key1, date1), (key2, date2), (key3, date3)])

dates.sort { p1, p2 in
    p1.aDateIChose < p2.aDateIChose
}
```

Comment: (1) Dictionary is not an ordered collection, so sorting a dictionary does not make sense. This is why I am using an array. (2) I need keys too. Just taking the values and sorting them is not enough. Keys storing values too, thus keys and values are both needed after the sort.

Comment: So each dict only has one entry? or which entry do you want to compare? I will add the code to my answer

Comment: One more question: If every dict only had one entry: why aren't you using tuples instead?

Comment: Yes, each dictionary has 1 entry. Your answer made me realize that I am using a wrong tool (dictionary) for this purpose. I probably should not store values as dictionary keys. Yes, tuples can be used too.